# How to update nested mat-tree dynamically

Tags: angular-material

I have an Angular material component that I am trying to update dynamically with new data.

```
@ViewChild('tree') tree: MatTree<any>;
...
treeControl: NestedTreeControl<any>;
dataSource: MatTreeNestedDataSource<any>;
...
// This does not work
this.tree.renderNodeChanges(newData);
```

I can change the data source data just fine and it is reflected in the logs, but the tree is never re-rendered `this.dataSource.data = newData`;

This data is retrieved from an observable and I pass it in every time there is a change.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [treeControl]="treeControl"
  #tree
  class="release-notes-tree">
  ...
</mat-tree>
```

**What is the easiest way to just pass in brand new data and update the tree?**

Comment: im having this exact same issue. One way to solve this is to set the data to null, then give it a value. For some reason that updates the view but I also get into memory leak problems which makes expanding nodes incredibly slow.

Answer (score 12):

Ive done some research into this which led to 2 new issues on the angular material github. It really isnt obvious whats going on here and Id argue its a bug.

triggers ngchange and updates the DOM

```
data = this.nestedDataSource.data
this.nestedDataSource.data = null;
this.nestedDataSource.data = data;
```

does not trigger ngchange

```
this.dataSource.data = newData
```

I havent tried to use this but supposedly this should work. Not sure why its not for you.

```
<mat-tree #treeSelector></mat-tree>
@ViewChild('treeSelector') tree: matTree;
this.tree.renderNodeChanges()
```

Comment: fair warning I also get a memory leak issue somehow so I also have to new up my datasource again after setting it to null. For reasons.

Comment: This works but this is incredibly slow. I have ~15 objects in a tree, just some checkbox, and a label styled by object properties. It gives 300ms delay, UI is unresponsive at this time, very odd comparing to the case when I'm not setting null

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just make the dataSource a Subject then when you want to change it call dataSource.next()  ?

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and is less funny looking than the provided 3 liner:

```
this.nestedDataSource.data = this.nestedDataSource.data.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = this.nestedDataSource.data;
this.nestedDataSource.data = null;
this.nestedDataSource.data = data;
```

Above will not trigger an onNgChange, because there really is no change. The change is evaluated after the method is completed. You can fake a change by duplicating the data in another structure with the same content. For example,

```
this.nestedDataSource.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.nestedDataSource.data));
```

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on this?: "You can fake a change by duplicating the data in another structure with the same content."

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me was overwriting the previous dataSource with a new one:

```
this.nestedDataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
this.nestedDataSource.data = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11381#issuecomment-575206296), the solution is using the **[Immutable Update](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)** to change the data source of the tree.
You can see a complete example here (but the important part is just the `updateObjectInArray` method):

```
import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';


export interface MenuItem {
    name: string;
    children?: MenuItem[];
}
/**
 * Update Type
 */
export interface UpType {
    index: number;
    item: MenuItem;
}

const TREE_DATA: MenuItem[] = [
    { name: 'Fruit', children: [{name: 'Apple'}, {name: 'Banana'}, {name: 'Fruit loops'}], },
    { name: 'Vegetables', children: [{name: 'Pumpkins'}, {name: 'Carrots'}], },
];


@Component({
  selector: 'mytree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.scss']
})
export class TreeComponent {
    treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<MenuItem>(node => node.children);
    dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<MenuItem>();

    constructor(private duplinkService: DuplinkService) {
        this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
    }

    hasChild = (_: number, node: MenuItem) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

    // other things ...

    updateData(): void {
        // the object with index 0 in tree data will be replaced by this one (updateAction.item)
        const updateAction =  {
            index: 0,
            item: { name: 'Fruit', children: [{name:'f1'}, {name:'f2'}, {name:'f3'}] }
        };
        this.dataSource.data = this.updateObjectInArray(this.dataSource.data, updateAction);
    }
    

    /**
     * Immutable update
     * @param array array to be updated
     * @param action UpType
     * @returns MenuItem[] updated array
     */
    private updateObjectInArray(array: MenuItem[], action: UpType): MenuItem[] {
        return array.map((item, index) => {
            if(index !== action.index) {
                // This isn't the item we care about - keep it as-is
                return item;
            }
            // Otherwise, this is the one we want - return an updated value
            return {
                ...item,
                ...action.item
            }
        });
    }
}
```